# Have cmake related files in a subdir under the project dir

Tags: build, cmake

I would like to have all cmake related files, i.e. `CMakeKists.txt`, `CMakeCache.txt`, `CMakeFiles/`, and `Makefile`; under a subdirectory of the project root directory, for example, `build_files/`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: simply put `CMakeLists.txt` there, and run CMake from that directory. You will have to refer to all source files etc. using absolute paths or relative paths that start with `..`, of course, but it will work.

**However**, note that it is **strongly** discouraged (and with good reason) to run in-source builds with CMake; that is, generating buildsystems somewhere within the source tree. If not for backwards compatibility, even allowing them would be long deprecated or even forbidden in CMake itself.

It's much better to generate the buildsystem into a directory separate from your entire source tree. Even so, you can keep the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `build_files`, if you wish. Assuming your source is located under `/path/source`, you would then do it like this:

```
cd /path
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../source/build_files
```

Comment: I am intending to have the `build_files/`, `src/`, and `bin/` directories as siblings of each other under the project root directory. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @rzjnzk It's certainly possible. However, as the answer says, I strongly suggest keeping all built & generated buildsystem files in their own directory. That could be `bin`, for example.